# Trying to display only one value in dropdown among four values

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I am appending four value to a dropdown using ajax,currently the values are not comma separated I want value to be displayed as comma separated and after selecting the value from dropdown list only one value Should be visible.
I mean currently value appear like this while selecting any of dropdown values.
'127Coil Wt1KGS'.IT should be visible like '127,Coil Wt,1,KGS'.And after selecting any of the dropdown value it should be visible like ‘Coil Wt’ only in dropdown place.

Ajax

```
$(function () {
    $("#Certific").click(function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "TDC.aspx/GetCertificate",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                var Certific = $("[id*=Certific]");
                $.each(r.d, function () {
                    Certific.append($("<option></option>").val(this['CE_VAL']).html([this['CE_VAL'], this['CE_DESC'], this['CE_SUB_VALUE'], this['CE_SUB_DESC']]));
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

C#

```
public static List<Certificate> GetCertificate(){

    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["abc"].ToString();
    OracleConnection objconn = new OracleConnection(connStr);
    string prop_name, tdc_property = "", qry = "";
    qry = "SELECT CE_VAL,CE_DESC,CE_SUB_VALUE,CE_SUB_DESC from code ";
    OracleCommand objFetchCmd = new OracleCommand(qry, objconn);
    List<Certificate> Certificate = new List<Certificate>();
    objconn.Open();        
    OracleDataReader ReadData = objFetchCmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (ReadData.Read()){

        Certificate.Add(new Certificate{ CODE_VALUE = ReadData["CE_VALUE"].ToString(),CODE_DESC = ReadData["CE_DESC"].ToString(), CODE_SUB_VALUE = ReadData["CE_SUB_VALUE"].ToString() , CODE_SUB_DESC = ReadData["CE_SUB_DESC"].ToString() });

    }
    objconn.Close();
    return Certificate;
}
```

Any Idea would be appreciated.

Comment: That makes no sense, I think you are describing it wrong. How and why would selecting any value always display "Coil Wt"?

Comment: @Crowcoder i mean among any of list of values in dropdown only second value should be display after selecting the value like among if dropdownvalue is 'a1b2' if user select this then second value 1 should be visible.

Comment: OK, I might understand now. Your `Option` value would be the second item but the `Option` content would be the entire string. You'll need some code to split on `,` to determine the second item.

Comment: @Crowcoder yes and only second elemet of any values should be shown after selecting a value from the list of dropdownlist value

Comment: @comma separation done only one want to display second value from comma separated.  Certific.append($("<option></option>").val(this['CODE_VALUE']).html([this['CE_VALUE'],',', this['CE_DESC'],',', this['CE_SUB_VALUE'],',', this['CE_SUB_DESC']]));